# 'C: Carriage return character detected' for 'module WareHouse' in Rubocop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, module, rubocop

I am using `rubocop` in my application. I am facing a issue that is `C: Carriage return character detected.`.

Here is my code.

```
module WareHouse
  class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Base
    # my code goes here
  end
end
```

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: Probably, you have run a command for git(which show some special character in `git diff`). Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you have a Windows-style line endings in your code. This could cause problems if you need to work with other developers using Mac or Linux machines.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/EndOfLine

If you don't care about this, you can disable or modify the EndOfLine rule's configuration:

https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml#L476